# imagettftext() function is not working in PHP

Tags: php

I am using imagettftext() function to put some text on image file but its not working with specific characters. As an ex:`'1234567890'` is my text but am getting `'123(some dummy symbol)567890'` on image. I don't know what that dummy symbol is.

Here is my code:

```
imagettftext($image, 22, 0, 100, 100, $black, '../ttf/Fontspring-DEMO-bwmodelica-regularultracondensed.otf', $phone_number);
```

Can anyone please help me that what is the issue? Do I need to change .otf file?

Comment: what's the output of `var_dump(urlencode($phone_number));`?

Comment: getting same some dummy symbol instead of 4

Comment: so, what's the output?

Comment: you mean what am getting on image? then it's 123(some dummy symbol)567890

Comment: I can't help you to debugging your code if you don't follow my instruction. _what's the **real** contents of `$phone_number`?_

Comment: It's phone number, which will be something like 123.456.789

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130403/discussion-between-federkun-and-user7).